# MoveIt Attach Object Error

Tags: ros, moveit, planning-scene, collision-object, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my node to add an object and attach it to the robot :

```
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
#include <moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h>
#include <geometric_shapes/shape_operations.h>

using namespace Eigen; 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "add_workpiece_wall");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

ros::AsyncSpinner spin(1);
spin.start();


moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface current_scene;
sleep(2.0);


Vector3d b(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);

moveit_msgs::CollisionObject co;            

co.id = "workpiece_wall";


shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://mitsubishi_rv6sd_support/meshes/workpiece_wall.stl",b); 
ROS_INFO("Workpiece Wall mesh loaded");

shape_msgs::Mesh mesh;

shapes::ShapeMsg mesh_msg;  
shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m, mesh_msg);
mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(mesh_msg);

co.meshes.resize(1);
co.mesh_poses.resize(1);

co.meshes[0] = mesh;
co.header.frame_id = "base_link";   

co.mesh_poses[0].position.x = 0.560651;
co.mesh_poses[0].position.y = 0.579113;
co.mesh_poses[0].position.z = 0.0;
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= 0.0; 
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= 0.0; 
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= 0.0;
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= 0.0;   

co.meshes.push_back(mesh);
co.mesh_poses.push_back(co.mesh_poses[0]);
co.operation = co.ADD;
    
    
std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> abc;
abc.push_back(co);


ROS_INFO("Workpiece Wall added into the world");
current_scene.addCollisionObjects(abc);
sleep(5.0);

moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup g("arm");     
ROS_INFO("Attach Workpiece Wall to the robot");
g.attachObject(co.id);
// Sleep to give Rviz time to show the object attached (different color).
sleep(4.0);


ros::shutdown();

return 0;
}
```

---

And the error I'm getting is this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  No Trajectory execution capability available.
[add_workpiece_wall-7] process has died [pid 47204, exit code -6, cmd /home/sbr/mitsubishi/devel/lib/mitsubishi_rv6sd_support/add_workpiece_wall __name:=add_workpiece_wall __log:=/home/sbr/.ros/log/d1c6e840-9ac0-11e6-ba06-480fcf447f3c/add_workpiece_wall-7.log].
log file: /home/sbr/.ros/log/d1c6e840-9ac0-11e6-ba06-480fcf447f3c/add_workpiece_wall-7*.log
```

---

From my [previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/245995/adding-collision-object-in-moveit/) it is somewhat clear that the error is only because of these lines :

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup g("arm");     
ROS_INFO("Attach Workpiece Wall to the robot");
g.attachObject(co.id);
// Sleep to give Rviz time to show the object attached (different color).
sleep(4.0);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246467/moveit-attach-object-error/) by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-26**:
Isn't this the same question as [MoveIt Attach Object std::runtime_error](http://answers.ros.org/question/246414)?

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-10-26**:
yes, but I had deleted that question before posting this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try and follow the instructions from the moveit.org website [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html?highlight=attach#adding-removing-objects-and-attaching-detaching-objects).  Your pose's quaternion is ill defined, the "w" component must be "1" if you are trying to set the orientation to identity.

---

Originally posted by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) with karma: 486 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-11-02**:
I set `w` equal to `1.0` but it still gives the same error.

**Comment by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) on 2016-11-02**:
Are you running the "move_group" separately?  It is required that the move_group node be running in order to service the **moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup** requests.

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-11-03**:
I am running this node after launching the `demo.launch` from my moveit config package. So `move_group` is being started automatically with `demo.launch`